# How to generate a specific query in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I need to generate a report that contains the number of sells for a specific product. (Clothing)

I have 4 tables:

- `Orders` contains the ID and the date
- `Product_Model` contains the model description and gender
- `Product_Type` contains the Product Model ID, price, size, color
- `Product_Order` contains a reference of "Orders" and a reference of "Product_Type"

What I need is generate a report showing, for example, the number of Male Blue T-Shirts in all months.

In this order: Product Model / Gender / Color

For examples:

[image]

[**Also check my simple representation in SQLFiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4333/4)

Thanks very much for this support! =)

Comment: What have you tried?  Questions get a better reception here when the poster has shown an effort to solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT MODEL, 
       GENDER, 
       COLOR, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 1 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) Jan, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 2 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) Feb, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 3 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) Mar, 
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN MONTH(ORDER_DATE) = 4 THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) Apr 
FROM   PRODUCT_MODELS t1 
       INNER JOIN PRODUCT_TYPES t2 
               ON t1.PRODUCT_MODEL_ID = t2.PRODUCT_MODEL_ID 
       INNER JOIN PRODUCT_ORDERS T3 
               ON t2.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = t3.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID 
       INNER JOIN ORDERS T4 
               ON T3.ORDER_ID = T4.ORDER_ID 
GROUP  BY MODEL, 
          GENDER, 
          COLOR
```

I used your SQL fiddle to cook up [my own example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c4333/21).

Comment: I really believe that any other answer couldn´t help me more than yours! Thank you very much!! =D

Answer (score 0):

An other solution can bu using [SQL Pivot Table query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-pivot-tables-in-sql-server-tutorial-with-examples.aspx) for your requirement

Here is the pivot query I build on your tables

```
with OrderReport as (
select
--  o.Order_ID,
--  date,
    DATENAME(Month,date) months,
    Order_Quantity,
--  Price,
--  Size,
--  Color,
--  model_description,
--  gender,
    product = model_description + ' / ' + gender + ' / ' + Color
from Orders o
inner join Product_Order po on po.Order_ID = o.Order_ID
inner join Product_Type t on t.Product_Type_ID = po.Product_Type_ID
inner join Product_Model m on m.Product_Model_ID = t.Product_Model_ID
) SELECT * FROM OrderReport
PIVOT (
    SUM(Order_Quantity)
    FOR months IN (
        [January],[February],[March],[April],
        [May],[June],[July],[August],
        [September],[October],[November],[December]
    )
) PivotTable
```

And here is DDL and some sample data for testing the pivot query

```
create table Product_Model (Product_Model_ID int, model_description nvarchar(50),     gender nvarchar(20))
create table Product_Type (Product_Type_ID int, Product_Model_ID int, price int, size nvarchar(20), color nvarchar(20))
create table Orders (Order_ID int, date datetime)
create table Product_Order (Order_ID int, Product_Type_ID int, Order_Quantity int)

insert into Product_Model select 1, 'Basic T-Shirt','Male'
insert into Product_Model select 2, 'Basic T-Shirt','Female'
insert into Product_Model select 3, 'Polo','Male'
insert into Product_Model select 4, 'Polo','Female'
insert into Product_Model select 5, 'Jacket','Male'
insert into Product_Model select 6, 'Jacket','Female'
insert into Product_Model select 7, 'Long T-Shirt','Female'

insert into Product_Type select 1,1,1,'1','Red'
insert into Product_Type select 2,1,1,'1','Blue'
insert into Product_Type select 3,2,1,'1','Cyano'
insert into Product_Type select 4,2,1,'1','Pink'
insert into Product_Type select 5,3,2,'1','Grey'
insert into Product_Type select 6,3,2,'1','Black'
insert into Product_Type select 7,4,2,'1','Blue'
insert into Product_Type select 8,4,2,'1','Red'

insert into Orders select 1,'20130131'
insert into Orders select 2,'20130110'
insert into Orders select 3,'20130216'
insert into Orders select 4,'20130220'
insert into Orders select 5,'20130311'
insert into Orders select 6,'20130311'

insert into Product_Order select 1,1,3
insert into Product_Order select 2,1,5
insert into Product_Order select 3,2,7
insert into Product_Order select 4,1,4
insert into Product_Order select 5,1,1
insert into Product_Order select 6,3,8
```

I hope this helps,